# nftables: IPv6 NAT packets not going into forward chain but returned destination unreachable

Tags: networking, ipv6, openwrt, nftables

I'm setting up NAT for IPv6 on an OpenWrt (22.03.0-rc4) router because my ISP only allocates one single IPv6 address via DHCPv6, and only allows one MAC address to use a single IPv6 address obtained last time via DHCPv6 (packets using other addresses will be dropped).

The latest version of OpenWrt is using firewall4 + nftables, so I decided to complete get rid of the legacy ip6tables and use the new one. I managed to let the router have access to IPv6 Internet and let the clients on LAN obtain IPv6 addresses (ULA addresses), but when I configured `masq6` for clients in LAN, the NAT6 does not work.

When I do Wireshark on my PC, it shows that all packets sent to the router for routing were rejected as "Destination Unreachable (no route to the host)". When I went to nftables tracing, I noticed that NO IPv6 PACKET from LAN hosts has ever reached the forward chain. These packets reached the dstnat chain (at prerouting), and disappeared from tracing, returning the PC a "Destination Unreachable". Even I create a new chain hooking at `forward` with a priority of -1000, no IPv6 packet can be seen.

Factually I managed to make it work yesterday (but I forgot how), but after a router reset, it fails again.

I doubt that there may be a missing or conflicting kernel module, so here's my lsmod:

```
cfg80211              298812  5 mt7615_common,mt7603e,mt76_connac_lib,mt76,mac80211
cmac                    2546  2 
compat                  1358  2 mac80211,cfg80211,[permanent]
crc_ccitt               1774  1 ppp_async
crc32c_generic          1458  1 
drbg                   17586  0 
gpio_button_hotplug     6674  0 
hmac                    2578  0 
hwmon                   8038  1 mt7615_common
ip_tables              11645  0 
ip6_tables             11331  0 
jitterentropy_rng       7561  0 
leds_gpio               3250  0 
libcrc32c                727  1 nf_tables
libsha256               8772  1 sha256_generic
mac80211              557288  5 mt7615e,mt7615_common,mt7603e,mt76_connac_lib,mt76
mt76                   48100  4 mt7615e,mt7615_common,mt7603e,mt76_connac_lib
mt76_connac_lib        26897  2 mt7615e,mt7615_common
mt7603e                40284  0 
mt7615_common          68934  1 mt7615e
mt7615e                11469  0 
netatop                35215  0 
nf_conntrack           71239  8 nft_redir,nft_nat,nft_masq,nft_flow_offload,nft_ct,nf_nat,nf_flow_table,nf_conntrack_bridge
nf_conntrack_bridge     3346  0 
nf_defrag_ipv4          1273  1 nf_conntrack
nf_defrag_ipv6          6036  2 nf_conntrack_bridge,nf_conntrack
nf_flow_table          23615  4 nf_flow_table_ipv6,nf_flow_table_ipv4,nf_flow_table_inet,nft_flow_offload
nf_flow_table_inet       658  0 
nf_flow_table_ipv4       530  0 
nf_flow_table_ipv6       530  0 
nf_log_common           3064  2 nf_log_ipv6,nf_log_ipv4
nf_log_ipv4             3762  0 
nf_log_ipv6             4050  0 
nf_nat                 24974  4 nft_redir,nft_nat,nft_masq,nft_chain_nat
nf_reject_ipv4          2601  3 nft_reject_ipv4,nft_reject_inet,nft_reject_bridge
nf_reject_ipv6          2926  3 nft_reject_ipv6,nft_reject_inet,nft_reject_bridge
nf_tables             153615203 nft_fib_inet,nf_flow_table_ipv6,nf_flow_table_ipv4,nf_flow_table_inet,nft_reject_ipv6,nft_reject_ipv4,nft_reject_inet,nft_reject_bridge,nft_reject,nft_redir,nft_quota,nft_objref,nft_numgen,nft_nat,nft_meta_bridge,nft_masq,nft_log,nft_limit,nft_hash,nft_flow_offload,nft_fib_ipv6,nft_fib_ipv4,nft_fib,nft_ct,nft_counter,nft_compat,nft_chain_nat
nfnetlink               5761  2 nft_compat,nf_tables
nft_chain_nat            946  2 
nft_compat              5874  0 
nft_counter             2226 18 
nft_ct                  7538  3 
nft_fib                 1622  3 nft_fib_inet,nft_fib_ipv6,nft_fib_ipv4
nft_fib_inet             754  0 
nft_fib_ipv4            2197  1 nft_fib_inet
nft_fib_ipv6            2869  1 nft_fib_inet
nft_flow_offload        3442  0 
nft_hash                2578  0 
nft_limit               3634  5 
nft_log                 1810  0 
nft_masq                1938  2 
nft_meta_bridge         1426  0 
nft_nat                 2738  0 
nft_numgen              1826  0 
nft_objref              1746  0 
nft_quota               2098  0 
nft_redir               1906  0 
nft_reject              1383  4 nft_reject_ipv6,nft_reject_ipv4,nft_reject_inet,nft_reject_bridge
nft_reject_bridge       4178  0 
nft_reject_inet         1234  2 
nft_reject_ipv4          754  0 
nft_reject_ipv6          754  0 
ppp_async               7330  0 
ppp_generic            25903  3 pppoe,ppp_async,pppox
pppoe                   9714  0 
pppox                   1520  1 pppoe
seqiv                   1682  0 
sha256_generic          2557  0 
slhc                    5538  1 ppp_generic
x_tables               17341  3 nft_compat,ip6_tables,ip_tables
```

and here's my `nft list ruleset`:

```
table inet fw4 {
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
                iifname "lo" accept comment "!fw4: Accept traffic from loopback"
                ct state established,related accept comment "!fw4: Allow inbound established and related flows"
                tcp flags syn / fin,syn,rst,ack jump syn_flood comment "!fw4: Rate limit TCP syn packets"
                iifname "br-lan" jump input_lan comment "!fw4: Handle lan IPv4/IPv6 input traffic"
                iifname "wan" jump input_wan comment "!fw4: Handle wan IPv4/IPv6 input traffic"
        }

        chain forward {
                type filter hook forward priority filter; policy drop;
                ct state established,related accept comment "!fw4: Allow forwarded established and related flows"
                iifname "br-lan" jump forward_lan comment "!fw4: Handle lan IPv4/IPv6 forward traffic"
                iifname "wan" jump forward_wan comment "!fw4: Handle wan IPv4/IPv6 forward traffic"
                jump handle_reject
        }

        chain output {
                type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
                oifname "lo" accept comment "!fw4: Accept traffic towards loopback"
                ct state established,related accept comment "!fw4: Allow outbound established and related flows"
                meta l4proto tcp counter packets 0 bytes 0 comment "!fw4: @rule[9]"
                meta l4proto udp counter packets 27 bytes 2192 comment "!fw4: @rule[9]"
                oifname "br-lan" jump output_lan comment "!fw4: Handle lan IPv4/IPv6 output traffic"
                oifname "wan" jump output_wan comment "!fw4: Handle wan IPv4/IPv6 output traffic"
        }

        chain handle_reject {
                meta l4proto tcp reject with tcp reset comment "!fw4: Reject TCP traffic"
                reject comment "!fw4: Reject any other traffic"
        }

        chain syn_flood {
                limit rate 25/second burst 50 packets return comment "!fw4: Accept SYN packets below rate-limit"
                drop comment "!fw4: Drop excess packets"
        }

        chain input_lan {
                jump accept_from_lan
        }

        chain output_lan {
                jump accept_to_lan
        }

        chain forward_lan {
                jump accept_to_wan comment "!fw4: Accept lan to wan forwarding"
                jump accept_to_lan
        }

        chain accept_from_lan {
                iifname "br-lan" counter packets 252 bytes 19093 accept comment "!fw4: accept lan IPv4/IPv6 traffic"
        }

        chain accept_to_lan {
                oifname "br-lan" counter packets 105 bytes 7472 accept comment "!fw4: accept lan IPv4/IPv6 traffic"
        }

        chain input_wan {
                meta nfproto ipv4 udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-DHCP-Renew"
                icmp type echo-request counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-Ping"
                meta nfproto ipv4 meta l4proto igmp counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-IGMP"
                meta nfproto ipv6 udp dport 546-547 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-DHCPv6"
                ip6 saddr fe80::/10 icmpv6 type . icmpv6 code { mld-listener-query . no-route, mld-listener-report . no-route, mld-listener-done . no-route, mld2-listener-report . no-route } counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-MLD"
                icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, time-exceeded, echo-request, echo-reply, nd-router-solicit, nd-router-advert } limit rate 1000/second counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-ICMPv6-Input"
                icmpv6 type . icmpv6 code { packet-too-big . no-route, parameter-problem . no-route, nd-neighbor-solicit . no-route, nd-neighbor-advert . no-route, parameter-problem . admin-prohibited } limit rate 1000/second counter packets 20 bytes 1440 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-ICMPv6-Input"
                jump reject_from_wan
        }

        chain output_wan {
                jump accept_to_wan
        }

        chain forward_wan {
                icmpv6 type { destination-unreachable, time-exceeded, echo-request, echo-reply } limit rate 1000/second counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-ICMPv6-Forward"
                icmpv6 type . icmpv6 code { packet-too-big . no-route, parameter-problem . no-route, parameter-problem . admin-prohibited } limit rate 1000/second counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept comment "!fw4: Allow-ICMPv6-Forward"
                meta l4proto esp counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump accept_to_lan comment "!fw4: Allow-IPSec-ESP"
                udp dport 500 counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump accept_to_lan comment "!fw4: Allow-ISAKMP"
                jump reject_to_wan
        }

        chain accept_to_wan {
                oifname "wan" counter packets 2123 bytes 133725 accept comment "!fw4: accept wan IPv4/IPv6 traffic"
        }

        chain reject_from_wan {
                iifname "wan" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump handle_reject comment "!fw4: reject wan IPv4/IPv6 traffic"
        }

        chain reject_to_wan {
                oifname "wan" counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump handle_reject comment "!fw4: reject wan IPv4/IPv6 traffic"
        }

        chain dstnat {
                type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        }

        chain srcnat {
                type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
                oifname "wan" jump srcnat_wan comment "!fw4: Handle wan IPv4/IPv6 srcnat traffic"
        }

        chain srcnat_wan {
                meta nfproto ipv4 masquerade comment "!fw4: Masquerade IPv4 wan traffic"
                meta nfproto ipv6 masquerade comment "!fw4: Masquerade IPv6 wan traffic"
        }

        chain raw_prerouting {
                type filter hook prerouting priority raw; policy accept;
                iifname "br-lan" jump helper_lan comment "!fw4: lan IPv4/IPv6 CT helper assignment"
        }

        chain raw_output {
                type filter hook output priority raw; policy accept;
        }

        chain helper_lan {
        }

        chain mangle_prerouting {
                type filter hook prerouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain mangle_postrouting {
                type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain mangle_input {
                type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain mangle_output {
                type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
        }

        chain mangle_forward {
                type filter hook forward priority mangle; policy accept;
                iifname "wan" tcp flags syn tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu comment "!fw4: Zone wan IPv4/IPv6 ingress MTU fixing"
                oifname "wan" tcp flags syn tcp option maxseg size set rt mtu comment "!fw4: Zone wan IPv4/IPv6 egress MTU fixing"
        }
}
```

The `sysctl.conf` is as default from OpenWrt (Do I need `wan.accept_ra = 2` ?):

```
net.core.bpf_jit_enable=1

net.ipv4.conf.default.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_ignore=1
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_broadcasts=1
net.ipv4.icmp_ignore_bogus_error_responses=1
net.ipv4.igmp_max_memberships=100
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time=120
net.ipv4.tcp_syncookies=1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps=1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack=1
net.ipv4.tcp_dsack=1

net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

A quick google-fu hasn't shown any related stuff about "v4 NAT working, but v6 NAT not working". Linked post on OpenWrt forum: https://forum.openwrt.org/t/ipv6-nat-in-v22-03-0-rc4-with-nftables-packets-not-flowing-into-forward-chain/130653

Let me know if `nft monitor trace` result or a pcap is needed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you actually have a default route? With forwarding=1, you do need accept_ra=2 for the kernel to pick up router advertisements (unless openwrt is doing RA in userspace). And does your ISP not offer a prefix via DHCPv6-PD like most do?

Comment: @user1686 It's my institution network, so no DHCPv6-PD or even a /64 prefix. Only one single address. `ip -6 route` shows that there is one default route, and I can use cURL to access IPv6 network. So it's definitely a firewall/config issue IMO.

Comment: I'll try accept_ra=2 later...

Answer (score 0):

It indeed works after I added `net.ipv6.conf.wan.accept_ra = 2` to `/etc/sysctl.conf`. Thanks to @user1686 !